# How to compare byte to byte in Java using FileInputStream

Tags: java, fileinputstream

can anyone write pseudocode to compare byte to byte in Java. I understand that we use read() to read byte to byte. but how do we do the comparison?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you give an example?

Comment: I have two files and I am trying to compare the contents inside the files from byte to byte so I will know if the file is changed or not. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what is unclear to you: just read 1 byte from both stream in every iteration of loop, if that byte from each stream is different, then it is the the same.  If the bytes are the same, keep working on next pair of bytes.  Loop until one of them reach end of file.  If at this point of time, both are end of file, then they are the same, if not, they are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot...

```
static boolean areFilesEqual (Path file1, Path file2) {
    byte[] f1 = Files.readAllBytes(file1); 
    byte[] f2 = Files.readAllBytes(file2);

    if (f1.length != f2.length) 
      return false;
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < f1.length; i++) {
          if (f1[i] != f2[i])
              return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't even Java. Path and Files are not in normal libary.

Answer (score 0):

I will not give you the actual code, because you should have the ability to translate this logic to real Java code.  If you do not, learn basics of Java first.

```
boolean compareStreams(InputStream is1, InputStream is2) {

    while (is1 is not end of stream && is2 is not end of stream) {
        b1 = is1.read();
        b2 = is2.read();
        if (b1 != b2) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (is1 is not end of stream || is2 is not end of stream) { 
    // only 1 of them reached end of stream but not the other
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// remember to close streams after use.
```

If you understand the above logic, base on the way Java Input Stream works, it can be further shrunk to

```
boolean compareStreams(InputStream is1, InputStream is2) {
    b1 = 0;
    b2 = 0;
    do {
        b1 = is1.read();
        b2 = is2.read();
        if (b1 != b2) {
            return false;
        }
    } while (b1 != -1 && b2 != -1);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: for larger files add a heartbeat to write something that process is still working, something like     String unitMessage 
    = ( bytesRead >> 29) >0 ? (bytesRead >> 29) + " Gbytes" 
    : ( bytesRead >> 19) >0 ? (bytesRead >> 19) + " Mbytes"
    : ( bytesRead >> 10) >0 ? (bytesRead >> 10) + " Kbytes"
    : bytesRead + " bytes";